# Push UIViewController after popping to root view

Tags: ios

I have an app using storyboards and a navigation controller. At some stage in my app flow I get about four views on the view stack at which point I must pop off all the views until I get to the root view. After which I need to manually push another view.

I've tried various things with no luck. I've tried to use the built-in API call:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

At which point I try to call a push segue by referencing the root view and calling the segue method.

```
RootView *obj = [[RootView alloc] init];
[obj callSegue];
```

Or

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushView" sender:self];
```

At any rate, I'm completely stumped on this one. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the replies everyone. I was digging around some more and found a solution, one of many I'm sure.

```
// Reference to navigation controller. Apparently if you use self.navigationController in a popToRootViewController call it sets self.navigationController to nil.
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

// Reference to view to push - must set storyboard ID in inspector
ViewToPush *viewRef = (ViewToPush *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameView"];
[navigationController pushViewController:gameView animated:NO];
```

Comment: Where do you call *[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushView" sender:self];* ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

`[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController, viewControllerTwo] animated:YES];`

This sets your stack to your root and a new controller and push animations are used. If you need a quick'n dirty reference for `rootViewController`, you can use `[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]`.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to this is to use an "Unwind Segue". Basically, an unwind segue is a segue that takes you back down the stack of pushed controllers, and then performs an `IBAction` method in the destination controller. What you want to do is make an unwind segue from your current controller to the root, and then put a `performSegueWithIdentifier:` call in the called method.

Here's a tutorial on unwind segues: [Tutorial](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues)

Answer (score 0):

Meybe you can try this :

- Set a flag (a `@property`) in your root VC, something like `shouldPushAutomatically`
- In the VC where you call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, implement the `prepareForSegue:WithIdentifier:` method. In this method, use `(MyVC*)segue.destinationViewController` to access your root VC and set yourflag to `YES`.
- In the `viewDidLoad` of your root VC, try calling your push segue (in fact, you may need to call it in `viewDidAppear`).

Not sure if this will work, but that's the way I would try to make it work.